# In C, how should I extract coefficients and exponents from polynomial input using strtok?

Tags: c

Say the user enters `"-4x^0 + x^1 + 4x^3 - 4x^5 - 3x^7"` as an input. I want to extract values from the string and pass them into `coef[]` and `expo[]` so it looks like this:

```
coef = [-4, 1, 0, 4, 0, -4, 0, -3]
expo = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,  5, 6,  7]
```

Here's what I have so far but I don't know how to use tokens.

```c
int main()
{
    char userInput[100];
    char temp[100];
    printf("Enter the polynomial: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", userInput);
    strcpy(temp, userInput);
    printf("\n");
    
    int coef[100];
    int expo[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        coef[i] = 0;
        expo[i] = 0;
    }
    
    char *tok = strtok(temp, "x^"); 
    int counter = 0;
    
    while (tok) { 
        printf("*%s*\n", tok); 
        tok = strtok(NULL, "x^"); 
        counter++; 
    } 
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried the following but it didn't work:

```c
    int counter = 0;
    while (tok) { 
        printf("*%s*\n", tok);        
        expo[counter] = atoi(tok);

        tok = strtok(NULL, "x^"); 
        counter++; 
    }
```

Comment: Why not use `char *delim = "x-+^\n";` and then read a coeff, then an exp, then next coeff and next exp, and so on? E.g. `strtok (temp, delim);` for the first call and then `strtok (NULL, delim);` for all subsequent calls until you run out of tokens in that line. Avoid using `atoi()` as it has NO error reporting and will happily accept `atoi ("My cow");` silently returning `0`. At least use `if (sscanf (tok, "%d", &coef[counter]) != 1) { /* handle error */ }`

Comment: You have complicated this question by requiring the use of stroke.  It is possible that simpler/better solution could be provided without that constraint.  Always best to avoid imposing unnecessary constraints on an answer.

Comment: I would also suggest reading the polynomial initially using a simple call to `fgets`.  In my opinion, the `scanf` format string `"%[^\n]%*c"` is insane, and not worth using.

Comment: It is possible to relax your language constraints, allowing maybe, "x^3 + 5 x^2-x+1", and more robust, less code, by using a [lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators#Regular_languages). [re2c](https://re2c.org/manual/manual_c.html) has examples that are very much like your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit trickier problem than I first presumed due to the whitespace in the user-input and the possibility of missing exponents and coefficients -- and coefficients missing due to being `1` and omitted.

This can be done, but it requires a *Decorate before you Tokenize* where you *decorate* the string to be tokenized with new delimiters between the exponents and coefficient to ensure you can use `strtok()`. Otherwise because the `+/-` must be kept and the input format can be, e.g. `"4x^1 + 3x^2"` there is no delimiter between the `1` and `3` except for whitespace surrounding the `'+'` that must be considered part of `3`.

A simple way to format the temporary string from the input is to remove all whitespace and add a new `'x'` between the exponent and coefficient. That allows you to use the same delimiter string with `strtok()`, e.g. `"x^\n"` without adjustment.

The missing coefficients and exponents can be handled by looping from the current index to the exponent assigning `0` for coefficients and the loop counter for the exponent. Then you can add the current coefficient and exponent.

Putting it altogether and using `sscanf()` to *minimally* validate each conversion from string to `int`, you can do something similar to the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC       1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXCOEF     256
#define MAXEXP  MAXCOEF
#define DELIM    "x^\n"

int main (void) {
  
    char buf[MAXC], tmp[MAXC];              /* input & reformat buffers */
    int coef[MAXCOEF] = {0},                /* coefficient array */
        expo[MAXEXP] = {0},                 /* exponent array */
        n = 0, ndx = 0;                     /* counter and index */
    
    fputs ("enter polynomial: ", stdout);   /* prompt */
    
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {        /* read line in buf/validate */
      puts ("(user canceled input)");
      return 0;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; buf[i]; i++) {          /* loop remormat buf in tmp */
      if (buf[i] != ' ') {                  /* if not space */
        if (buf[i] == '-' || buf[i] == '+') { /* if before next coef */
          tmp[n++] = 'x';                     /* decorate with new 'x' */
        }
        tmp[n++] = buf[i];                  /* add from buf to tmp */
      }
      else {  /* otherwise was ' ' */
        if (buf[i+1] == 'x') {              /* if next char is 'x' */
          tmp[n++] = '1';                   /* coef not given - use 1 */
        }
      }
    }
    tmp[n] = 0;   /* nul-terminate tmp */
    
    /* separate each token with strtok */
    for (char *tok = strtok (tmp, DELIM); tok; tok = strtok (NULL, DELIM)) {
      int ctmp, etmp;   /* temp values for coefficient and exponent */
      
      if (sscanf (tok, "%d", &ctmp) != 1) { /* convert coefficient to int */
        fprintf (stderr, "conversion failed for '%s'.\n", tok);
        return 1;
      }
      
      if (!(tok = strtok (NULL, DELIM))) {  /* get exponent token */
        break;
      }
      if (sscanf (tok, "%d", &etmp) != 1) { /* convert exponent to int */
        fprintf (stderr, "conversion failed for '%s'.\n", tok);
        return 1;
      }
      
      for (int i = ndx; i < etmp; i++) {    /* loop index to exponent */
        coef[ndx] = 0;                      /* add any missing values */
        expo[ndx++] = i;                    /* increment index */
      }
      
      coef[ndx] = ctmp;                     /* add coefficient & exponent */
      expo[ndx++] = etmp;                   /* increment index */
    }
    
    fputs ("\ncoef:", stdout);              /* output coefficients */
    for (int i = 0; i < ndx; i++) {
      printf (" % d", coef[i]);
    }
    putchar ('\n');   /* tidy up with newline */
    
    fputs ("expo:", stdout);                /* output exponents */
    for (int i = 0; i < ndx; i++) {
      printf (" % d", expo[i]);
    }
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtokpoly
enter polynomial: -4x^0 + x^1 + 4x^3 - 4x^5 - 3x^7

coef: -4  1  0  4  0 -4  0 -3
expo:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

Which corresponds to your needed output.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 2):

`strtok()` is not a good approach for this problem, especially using `"x^"` as the list of separators because it will overwrite these characters with null bytes, hence making it impossible to distinguish `2x` from `2`.

Also note that `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", userInput)` has undefined behavior if the polynomial entered by the user is longer than 99 bytes.  The return value of `scanf()` should be tested to detect an unexpected end of file. It is safer to use `fgets()` and test the return value.

To parse the polynomial, it is recommended to test one character at a time and convert numbers with `strtol` or a similar function.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned char skip_spaces(char *p, char **pp) {
    unsigned char c;
    while (isspace(c = *p))
        p++;
    *pp = p;
    return c;
}

void show_error(const char *error, const char *str, const char *p) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n%s%*s^\n", error, str, (int)(p - str), "");
}

#define TERM_COUNT 100

int main() {
    char userInput[100];

    printf("Enter the polynomial: ");
    if (fgets(userInput, sizeof userInput, stdin)) {
        int coef[TERM_COUNT] = { 0 };
        int expo[TERM_COUNT] = { 0 };
        int counter;
        char *p = userInput;

        for (counter = 0; counter < TERM_COUNT; counter++) {
            int sign = 1;
            unsigned char c = skip_spaces(p, &p);
            if (c == '\0')
                break;
            if (c == '+') {
                c = skip_spaces(p + 1, &p);
            } else
            if (c == '-') {
                sign = -1;
                c = skip_spaces(p + 1, &p);
            }
            if (c == '\0') {
                show_error("missing term", userInput, p);
                break;
            }
            if (isdigit(c)) {
                coef[counter] = sign * strtol(p, &p, 10);
                c = skip_spaces(p, &p);
            } else {
                coef[counter] = sign;
            }
            if (c == 'x') {
                c = skip_spaces(p + 1, &p);
                if (c == '^') {
                    c = skip_spaces(p + 1, &p);
                    if (isdigit(c)) {
                        expo[counter] = strtol(p, &p, 10);
                        c = skip_spaces(p, &p);
                    } else {
                        show_error("missing exponent", userInput, p);
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    expo[counter] = 1;
                }
            } else {
                expo[counter] = 0;
            }
            if (c != '\0' && c != '+' && c != '-') {
                show_error("syntax error", userInput, p);
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            printf("%+dx^%d", coef[i], expo[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code uses your approach and populates 2 arrays with the coefficients and exponents.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little too complex to do with strtok, as you have all kinds of corner cases with implicit coefficients and such.  You could go the full-parsing route and use lex & yacc, but that is probably overkill.  A hybrid approach is to use fgets + sscanf to match specific patterns.  Something like:

```
int main() {
    char userInput[100] = { 0 };
    printf("Enter the polynomial: ");
    fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin);
    printf("\n");
    
    int coef[100] = { 0 };
    int expo[100] = { 0 };
    int i = 0;
    char *p = userInput;
    while (p && *p && i < 100) {
        int len;
        if (i == 0 && sscanf(p, "%d x ^%d %n", &coef[i], &expo[i], &len) == 2)) {
        } else if (sscanf(p, " +%d x ^%d %n", &coef[i], &expo[i], &len) == 2)) {
        } else if (sscanf(p, " -%d x ^%d %n", &coef[i], &expo[i], &len) == 2)) {
            coef[i] = -coef[i];
        } else if (i == 0 && sscanf(p, " x ^%d %n", &expo[i], &len) == 1) {
            coef[i] = 1;
        } else if (sscanf(p, " + x ^%d %n", &expo[i], &len) == 1) {
            coef[i] = 1;
        } else if (sscanf(p, " - x ^%d %n", &expo[i], &len) == 1) {
            coef[i] = -1;
        } else if (sscanf(p, " +%d x %n", &coeff[i], &len) == 1) {
            expo[i] = 1;
        } else if (sccanf(p, " -%d x %n", &coeff[i], &len) == 1) {
            coef[i] = -coef[i];
            expo[i] = 1;
        } else if (i == 0 && sccanf(p, "%d x %n", &coeff[i], &len) == 1) {
            expo[i] = 1;
        } else if (sscanf(p, " +%d %n", &coeff[i], &len) == 1) {
            expo[i] = 0;
        } else if (sccanf(p, " -%d %n", &coeff[i], &len) == 1) {
            coef[i] = -coef[i];
            expo[i] = 0;
        } else if (i == 0 && sccanf(p, "%d %n", &coeff[i], &len) == 1) {
            expo[i] = 0;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "this doesn't look like a polynomial: %s\n", p);
            break;
        }
        p += len;
        ++i;
    }

    printf("got polynomial: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        printf("%+dx^%d", coef[j], expo[j]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Note that this can get pretty complex fast, with lots of different corner cases to check, but for simpler things may be easier than using a full parser.